# How to complete my proof of Burnside's Lemma?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I try to prove the Burnside's Lemma:

> If $X$ is a finite $G$-set and $N$ is the number of $G$-orbits of $X$, then $N=(1/|G|)\sum_{\tau \in G} F(\tau)$, where $\tau \in G$, $F(\tau)$ is the number of $x\in X$ fixed by $\tau$.

My proof is stuck as somepoint.

I define $\delta_{gx}= 1$ if $gx=g$ and 0 if not. Then
$$
\sum_{\tau \in G}F(\tau)=\sum_{\tau \in G}\sum_{x\in X}\delta_{\tau s}=\sum_{x\in X} |stab_G(x)|
$$

By orbit stabilizer theorem, $|G|=|stab_G(x)||O(x)|$, then
$$
\sum_{\tau \in G}F(\tau)=\sum_{x\in X} \frac{|G|}{O(x)}
$$

But why can we get
$$
\sum_{x\in X} \frac{1}{O(x)}=N
$$

Comment: Why they have the same size for $|O(x)|=|O(y)|$? I mean the set $|S|=|O(x_1)|+\dots |O(x_n)|$.

Comment: I think that should be "As all elements in the same orbit have same size of stabilizer", right?

Comment: Same thing, by the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem.